# SQL Truncate vs SQL Truncate in batches

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a job that populates staging tables and once is done it truncate several staging tables in one store procedure. The issue I am having is that sometimes all this tables don't truncate causing PK constraint in the next insert since they are not empty. I don't know if its because I don't have enough DTUs in Azure. 
Do the truncates occur in parallel or does it wait for one to finish before moving to the next?
Should I do this in batches? What are the PROS and CONS?

Not working all the time

```
CREATE PROCEDURE truncate_tables
  AS
    BEGIN
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table1;
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table2;
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table3;
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table4;
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table5;
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table6;
    END
```

Suggestion

```
CREATE PROCEDURE truncate_tables
  AS
    BEGIN
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table1;
     GO
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table2;
     GO
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table3;
     GO
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table4;
     GO
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table5;
     GO
     TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table6;
     GO
    END
```

Comment: If you have FK/PK defined running in batches won't help.  Refer to this post to understand how to achieve this - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190073/truncate-tables-with-dependent-foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Your "suggestion" isn't going to parse. Stored procedures can't contain multiple batches. On the other hand, you don't have to be worried about things happening in parallel when you don't want them to either -- T-SQL is a strictly sequential language, even though individual statements may be executed with more than one processor.

Comment: @rs the PK issue happens on the next insert because the tables did not truncate.

Comment: "The issue I am having is that sometimes all this tables don't truncate" why?

Comment: @Apollo, did you try running each one at a time and look for any errors?  Can you do that and let us know if you see any errors or they complete ok

Comment: @rs I tried running this one at a time and no errors. I run all of them I get no errors. Is only when its installed in the server.

Comment: Just for clarification adding `GO` doesnt make a difference in this case. All truncate statements within the stored procedure are executed sequentially not in parallel.

Comment: "Only when installed on the server". That still doesn't say what (if any) errors there are? Is the process that's actually doing the truncate running as a different account? Does that account have the right permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may get a better result if you kill existing connections except the current one:

DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';

```
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'KILL ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), c.session_id) + ';'

FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
    ON c.session_id = s.session_id
WHERE c.session_id <> @@SPID
--WHERE status = 'sleeping'
ORDER BY c.connect_time ASC

EXEC(@kill)
```

I have seen this issue in the past with databases having many user connections.

Another option scale a tier, truncate the tables, scale down.